# Android Studio Connect Database to Class And then to Activity Edit Text

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have tried several things and none of them seem to work with crashing the app.  So I went back to the beginning again and removed all references that saves and gets information from the BusinessInfo class.

If someone can take a look and let me know what the missing pieces are that will tie these three classes together and populate an edittext.settext, I would be so grateful for the assistance and not only fill in the missing code, but also explain the code that was missing and then filled in.

Simplified Objective:

1. Populate EditText in an Activity from a Class from sqlite database.

First Thing:  Create the class.

```
    package com.example.dbtoedittext;

public class BusinessInfo {

    private String Company_Name;
    private String OwnersName;

public BusinessInfo(String company_Name, String ownersName) {
        Company_Name = company_Name;
        OwnersName = ownersName;
    }

    public String getCompany_Name() {
        return Company_Name;
    }

    public String getOwnersName() {
        return OwnersName;
    }


    public void setCompany_Name(String company_Name) {
        Company_Name = company_Name;
    }

    public void setOwnersName(String ownersName) {
        OwnersName = ownersName;
    }

}
```

Create The DatabaseHelper

```
    package com.example.dbtoedittext;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public static final String OWNER_TABLE = "OWNER_TABLE";
    public static final String COL_BUSINESS_NAME = "BUSINESS_NAME";
    

    public DataBaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, "dbtoedittext.db", null, 1);
    }

    //Called First Time It's Run
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    //Creates Initial Table
    String createTableStatement = "CREATE TABLE " + OWNER_TABLE + "(" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COL_BUSINESS_NAME + " TEXT," + COL_BUSINESS_OWNERS_NAME;
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(createTableStatement);

    //Inserts Initial Data Into Table
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_BUSINESS_NAME, "MyBusiness");
        cv.put(COL_BUSINESS_OWNERS_NAME, "MyNameIs");
        sqLiteDatabase.insert(OWNER_TABLE,null,cv);

    }

    //Called When database Version Changes
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    }

    public void get_BusinessInfo(){
        //Get Data From Database
        String queryString = "Select * FROM " + OWNER_TABLE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String businessName =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_BUSINESS_NAME));
        String businessOwnerName = 
        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_BUSINESS_OWNERS_NAME));
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Now my activity:

```
    package com.example.dbtoedittext;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.List;

public class EditBasicBusinessInfoConfigurationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Define Fields
    EditText editTextBusinessName;
    EditText editTextBusinessOwnersName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_basic_business_info_configuration);

        //initialize Form Fields
        editTextBusinessName = findViewById(R.id.editTextBusinessName);
        editTextBusinessOwnersName = findViewById(R.id.editTextBusinessOwnersName);

        //Initialize Database
        DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new 
        DataBaseHelper(EditBasicBusinessInfoConfigurationActivity.this);

        //Call get_BusinessInfo from dataBaseHelper
        dataBaseHelper.get_BusinessInfo();
        editTextBusinessName.setText(businessInfo.getCompany_Name());
    }
}
```

So what am I missing to tie the database data to the class and then to the edittext.settext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **get_BusinessInfo** method returns nothing, when I believe that you intend for it to return a **BusinessInfo** object.

The following is perhaps what you want :-

```
public BusinessInfo get_BusinessInfo(){
    //Get Data From Database
    String queryString = "Select * FROM " + OWNER_TABLE;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    String businessName =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_BUSINESS_NAME));
    String businessOwnerName = 
    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_BUSINESS_OWNERS_NAME));
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return new BusinessInfo(businessName,businessOwnerName);
}
```

You then want to retrieve the BusinessInfo so :-

```
    BusinessInfo myBusinessInfo = dataBaseHelper.get_BusinessInfo();
    editTextBusinessName.setText(myBusinessInfo.getCompany_Name());
```

- Note the above is in-principle code and has not been tested and may therefoore contains small errors.
- Note that not checking if the cursor.MoveToFirst in fact moved (in case the Cursor is empty) is recommended otherwise you may encounter errors.

e.g.

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst) {
    //.... do something if the first row exists
} else {
    //.... handle nothing found here
}
```